# docker: Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)

Tags: docker

Trying an example from the "Docker in Action" book.

```
$docker run -d --name wp2 --link wpdb:mysql -p 80 --read-only wordpress:4
```

... should have triggered this error ...

```
    Read-only file system: AH00023: Couldn't create the rewrite-map mutex
(file /var/lock/apache2/rewrite-map.1)”
```

but it did not.
It triggered a file descriptor error ...

```
$docker logs wp2
WordPress not found in /var/www/html - copying now...
Complete! WordPress has been successfully copied to /var/www/html
Wed Dec  9 23:15:21 2015 (21): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)
Wed Dec  9 23:15:21 2015 (30): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)
Wed Dec  9 23:15:21 2015 (39): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)
Wed Dec  9 23:15:21 2015 (48): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)
Wed Dec  9 23:15:22 2015 (62): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)
Wed Dec  9 23:15:22 2015 (76): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)
Wed Dec  9 23:15:22 2015 (90): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)
Wed Dec  9 23:15:22 2015 (104): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)
Wed Dec  9 23:15:22 2015 (118): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)
Wed Dec  9 23:15:22 2015 (132): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)
Wed Dec  9 23:15:22 2015 (146): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)
Wed Dec  9 23:15:22 2015 (160): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)
Wed Dec  9 23:15:22 2015 (164): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)
```

The book suggested that we could make this work using volumes like so ...

```
$docker run -d --name wp3 --link wpdb:mysql -p 80 -v /var/lock/apache2/ -v /var/run/apache2/ --read-only wordpress:4
305e62e18d926a54ac7d1a0fb775f61efdb61486d9d9245933c3b18055bd9856
```

container "seems" to start ok
but it did not ...

```
$docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
6bd4d90f594b        mysql:5             "/entrypoint.sh mysql"   21 minutes ago      Up 21 minutes       3306/tcp            wpdb
```

the logs say this ...

```
$docker logs wp3
WordPress not found in /var/www/html - copying now...
Complete! WordPress has been successfully copied to /var/www/html
Wed Dec  9 23:31:57 2015 (22): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)
Wed Dec  9 23:31:57 2015 (31): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)
Wed Dec  9 23:31:57 2015 (40): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)
Wed Dec  9 23:31:57 2015 (49): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)
Wed Dec  9 23:31:57 2015 (63): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)
Wed Dec  9 23:31:58 2015 (77): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)
Wed Dec  9 23:31:58 2015 (91): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)
Wed Dec  9 23:31:58 2015 (105): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)
Wed Dec  9 23:31:58 2015 (119): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)
Wed Dec  9 23:31:58 2015 (133): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)
Wed Dec  9 23:31:58 2015 (147): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)
Wed Dec  9 23:31:58 2015 (161): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)
Wed Dec  9 23:31:58 2015 (165): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)
```

I'm not sure why this is happening.
The book I am reading says that this should work.
I was not able to find any examples of anyone else who was getting this particular error.
Removing the --read-only flag entirely does work.

```
$docker run -d --name wp3 --link wpdb:mysql -p 80 -v /var/lock/apache2/ -v /var/run/apache2/ wordpress:4
990874c73691c42d3c04aceb19f83a698f90a2f9ddcf1c07fb3cc9b9f1986723

$docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                   NAMES
990874c73691        wordpress:4         "/entrypoint.sh apach"   5 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        0.0.0.0:32773->80/tcp   wp3
6bd4d90f594b        mysql:5             "/entrypoint.sh mysql"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    3306/tcp                wpdb
```

Comment: It's probably not going to make you feel any better, but I'm having the same problem with this example from 'Docker in Action'.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is similar to @allingeek's solution, but I couldn't get that to work without explicitly allowing access to /tmp:

```
docker run -d --name wp --read-only -v /run/lock/apache2/ -v /run/apache2/ -v /tmp/ --link wpdb:mysql -p 80 wordpress:4
```

Without `-v /tmp/` I still got the "Bad file descriptor" log output.

Comment: This is also the one that worked for me. Tested basic WP installation after and worked OK

Comment: @allingeek is the "Bad file descriptor" error because wordpress isn't able to successfully change the file permissions unless we add the `/tmp` volume? In your analysis it shows that `/tmp` was changed, did you just forget to add it in your final command or was that intentional?

Answer (score 19):

The quick fix for this issue is to use an older version of the WordPress image. It seems that they changed their file locking mechanisms between 4.2 and 4.3. So, the commands become:

```
$docker run -d --name wp2 --link wpdb:mysql -p 80 --read-only wordpress:4.2
$docker run -d --name wp3 --link wpdb:mysql -p 80 -v /var/lock/apache2/ -v /var/run/apache2/ --read-only wordpress:4.2
```

Going deeper, it looks like the WordPress image changed the locations where it writes these files. To discover the differences I took the following steps:

- Start up a wordpress:4 container without the read-only file system
- Examine the file system changes to the container
- Change the example to create the volumes at the new locations

This analysis ran as follows:

```
# Create the writable container
$ docker run -d --name wp10 --link wpdb:mysql -p 80 wordpress:4

# Examine the differences
$ docker diff wp10
C /run
C /run/apache2
A /run/apache2/apache2.pid
C /run/lock
C /run/lock/apache2
C /tmp

# Update the example for the new locations
$ docker run -d --name wp15 --read-only -v /run/lock/apache2/ -v /run/apache2/ --link wpdb:mysql -p 80 wordpress:4
```

As you can see, the image moved the PID and lock files from /var to /run, and added a write dependency on /tmp. Understanding this analysis is important if you are going to translate this tactic to a different example.

Comment: @crownedjitter Would you make sure this works for you? I'm updating the book for the final print.

Answer (score 0):

answer to comment above - no, it does not fix the issue, wp comes up and stays up. but fails to connect to mysql. in-turn agent fails and exits
sorry in advance, i don't have enough reputations to comment above.

tl;dr

first run, to start from a known point

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)  # CAUTION: this removes ALL your containers!!!
```

Then run this script

```
#!/bin/bash
# CLIENT_ID must be set or need to use script cmdline arg

docker-name() {
  docker inspect --format '{{ .Name }}' "$@"
}
docker-ip() {
  docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' "$@"
}

CLIENT_ID=DUKE

DB_CID=$(docker run -d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=ch2demo mysql:5)

MAILER_CID=$(docker run -d dockerinaction/ch2_mailer)

if [ ! -n "$CLIENT_ID" ]; then 
  echo "Client ID not set"
  exit 1
fi

# NOTE: using wordpress:4.2 not latest/4.3 read-only dirs changed
WP_CID=$(docker create \
  --link $DB_CID:mysql \
  --name wp_$CLIENT_ID \
  -p 80 \
  -v /var/lock/apache2/ \
  -v /var/run/apache2/ \
  -e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=$CLIENT_ID \
  --read-only wordpress:4.2)
docker start $WP_CID

AGENT_CID=$(docker create \
  --name agent_$CLIENT_ID \
  --link $WP_CID:insideweb \
  --link $MAILER_CID:insidemailer \
  dockerinaction/ch2_agent)
docker start $AGENT_CID

echo "    Client ID: $CLIENT_ID"
echo "     MySQL ID: $(docker-name $DB_CID) IP: $(docker-ip $DB_CID)" 
echo "    Mailer ID: $(docker-name $MAILER_CID) IP: $(docker-ip $MAILER_CID)" 
echo " Wordpress ID: $(docker-name $WP_CID) IP: $(docker-ip $WP_CID)" 
echo "     Agent ID: $(docker-name $AGENT_CID) IP: $(docker-ip $AGENT_CID)"
```

output:

```
    Client ID: DUKE
     MySQL ID: /thirsty_sammet IP: 172.17.0.2
    Mailer ID: /sleepy_snyder IP: 172.17.0.3
 Wordpress ID: /wp_DUKE IP: 172.17.0.4
     Agent ID: /agent_DUKE IP:
```

run

```
docker ps -a

IMAGE                       COMMAND                  STATUS                     PORTS                   NAMES
dockerinaction/ch2_agent    "/watcher/watcher.sh"    Exited (0) 2 minutes ago                           agent_DUKE
wordpress:4.2               "/entrypoint.sh apach"   Up 2 minutes               0.0.0.0:32773->80/tcp   wp_DUKE
dockerinaction/ch2_mailer   "/mailer/mailer.sh"      Up 2 minutes               33333/tcp               sleepy_snyder
mysql:5                     "/entrypoint.sh mysql"   Up 2 minutes               3306/tcp                thirsty_sammet
```

so wordpress comes up and stays up, but agent fails and exits

```
docker logs agent_DUKE
nc: can't connect to remote host (172.17.0.4): Connection refused
```

Wordpress is failing to connet to mysql but does not exit

```
docker logs wp_DUKE
WordPress not found in /var/www/html - copying now...
Complete! WordPress has been successfully copied to /var/www/html

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in - on line 10

MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in - on line 10

MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in - on line 10

MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sun Jan 03 23:37:38.773659 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) PHP/5.6.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jan 03 23:37:38.773802 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
```

running: docker host is vmware ubuntu 14.04x64 DT on win7x64 host